# WPF ClickOnce missed references

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, clickonce

I have a WPF app that works with local SQLite and Entity Framework Core. I want to distribute my app using ClickOnce.

Everything works fine when I run it using Visual Studio 2017. But app had a crash on a start when I used ClickOnce. The crash was so early so I couldn't even log the exception. After some time I found that in publish folder some dlls were missed. For example System.Runtime. All references are NuGet packages. Then I found that despite of I have a reference to the dlls in my project ClickOnce application files list doesn't contains it.

The only solution I have found for now is to add missed dlls as files in root of my project and set build action to Content. In ClickOnce application file dialog I set publish status to Include.

It works now but it looks like not the best way to do it. The question is why they are missed in the first place. More likely I missed something or I am not understand the root of the problem.

UPD:

You can find an example code [here](https://github.com/ichepikov/ClickOnceTest/tree/missing-dlls).

It works from Visual Studio but crashes on a start when you try to install it as ClickOnce application.

UPD: The problem was fixed in Visual Studio Professional version 15.6.1

Comment: @Pikoh As I said: "despite of I have a reference to the dlls in my project ClickOnce application files list doesn't contains it"

Comment: @Pikoh I didn't have it at all in the list before I added them as common files to the project.

Comment: Do you have in the reference "Local copy" set to true?

Comment: @Pikoh Yes I Do.

Comment: I've just tried with a test application to add the Entity Framework Core package and it automatically shows up in "Application files", so i can't help you more. Sorry

Comment: @Pikoh Thanks for your help. I have updated my question and you can now find my example there. And again at least System.Runtime.dll is missing.

Comment: ok,try this. Edit your app.config and change every place you see '4.1.1.0' for '4.0.0.0' . Publish your app and see if it works. I think there's some bug, see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4171) for example.

Comment: @Pikoh All is the same.

Comment: Go to Project properties->Publish->Application Files and set the Publish Status of your dlls  to "Include"

Comment: i work on click once for 2 years and know the problems of this please do my answers way and if it not work tell me to help you

Comment: hه Friend i doد this and updated my answer for your sample ;-)

Comment: didn't give me bounty? ;-)

Comment: @ShahroozAnsari sorry it is the first time I created bounty. I thought that if I accept an answer it will work automatically. now it should work. And thank you again for helping me :)

Comment: you'r welcome friend :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are two ways solving solve this**.

At first, you have to go *Properties* → *Publish* → *Application Files*, and at this place, make your DLL files **include** in your project

[image: This place]

But if it does not work, go to References and make the DLL file **CopyLocal = False**. You add a DLL file like *Existing Item* in your project and make them **Copy Always**.

[image: DLL file and copy always]

It will work correctly.

But for your sample I watch this and I solved it. Look at this image:

[image]

You have four DLL files. You need do this for them:

```
System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
System.Reflection.dll
System.Runtime.dll
System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
```

At first go to your reference and make them **Copy Local False**:

[image]

Then go to the path of each DLL file and add them like *Existing Item*, and then make all of them **Copy To Output Directory CopyAlways**

[image]

Then *Publish* it and run it like in this picture. I run it from publish file and it works.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I don't have the libraries in properties > publish >Application. The second solution works but it is described in the question.

Comment: can you give me team viewer  too i remote your system and see code and system on your system?

Comment: thanks for your interest and your time! In the question a have added a link to [githab](https://github.com/ichepikov/ClickOnceTest/tree/missing-dlls) could you check the example? Or it works on your environment?

Comment: I Updated My answer and tested that ;)

Comment: More importantly - why is this happening and can you fix this so you can just use copylocal=true. This is an inane solution that does work.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set the dll to copy local, the dll will not get copied over unless you actually use the dll in your code.  You might try adding System.Runtime in your code somewhere like this maybe?

```
     var dummytest = System.Runtime.GCSettings.IsServerGC;
```

Comment: My code doesn't have direct references to the library but it should be added because it is used by other libraries using in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Issue 9 on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb/ I was able to do the following:

## Symptom

ClickOnce applications targeting .NET Framework 4.0 that reference the `Microsoft.Bcl` or `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` packages may experience a `TypeLoadException` or other errors after being installed.

## Resolution

This occurs because ClickOnce fails to deploy certain required assemblies. As a workaround, do the following:

1. Right-click on the project and choose **Add Existing Item**
2. Browse to the folder where the **System.Runtime.dll** lives
3. In the **File name** text box paste in the path of the file
4. Click the down-arrow next to the Add button and choose **Add as Link**
5. In Solution Explorer, holding **CTRL** select **System.Runtime.dll**
6. Right-click the selection, choose **Properties** and change **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy always**
7. Republish