# Clickonce not including NuGet System.Runtime DLL for deployment because a different version exists in GAC

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

- We have an application that uses nuget package X.
- Nuget package X uses nuget package System.Runtime 4.1.1.0
- Our application has a reference to System.Runtime 4.1.1.0 with CopyLocal=true
- System.Runtime 4.0.0.0 exists in the GAC as part of the .NET Framework

Unfortunately for us, because Sys.Runtime 4.0.0.0 is in the GAC, ClickOnce therefore doesn't include System.Runtime 4.1.1.0 in our deployment package.

Our application therefore throws an exception saying System.Runtime 4.1.1.0 isn't found on startup.

Any way to force System.Runtime 4.1.1.0 to be included in the package? I tried editing the project file manually, but to no avail.

- Under the 'application files' button of the 'Publish' tab, System.Runtime is not available.

Thanks

Added screenshot of reference in application project:
[image]

Comment: friend i answered this question please look at this link my answer and dont forget vote up them and approve them if there was any problem again i worked for 2 years on click once just comented ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absense of an offical clickonce fix, here is a workaround:

1. Paste in the following class to your application
2. Create a folder called 'ClickOnceSucks'
3. Place the DLLs that you're having problems with in this folder.
4. Set the DLLs as type Embedded Resource
5. Set your application entrypoint to 'AppStartupHook'

   public class AppStartupHook
   {
       [STAThread]
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           ClickOnceSucks();

   ```
       App.Main();
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Copies the embedded resources into the application path before startup.
   /// </summary>
   private static void ClickOnceSucks()
   {
       const string folderName      = "ClickOnceSucks";
       const string structureFormat = "{0}.{1}.";

       var assembly        = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
       var resourceFolder  = structureFormat.FormatCurrent(assembly.GetName().Name, folderName);

       //Find all resources in the clickoncesucks folder and copy them to our path.
       assembly
           .GetManifestResourceNames()
           .Where(each => each.StartsWith(resourceFolder, StringComparison.Ordinal))
           .Select(each => new
           {
               Name = each.Replace(resourceFolder, string.Empty),
               Data = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(each)
           })
           .Where(each => !File.Exists(each.Name))
           .ForEach(each =>
           {
               using (var fileStream = new FileStream(each.Name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                   each.Data.CopyTo(fileStream);
           });
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756396/wpf-clickonce-missed-references/43823551#43823551) of my answer.

There have problem like you. You just need do the second way I wrote for this question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into your project and ensure there is a reference to Sys.Runtime 4.1.1.0.
2. Right click the reference in solution explorer and choose Properties
3. On the property sheet for the reference, **set "Specific Version" to true**.
4. Clean/build all.
5. Rebuild your ClickOnce installer and test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but these are all set correctly. I've rebuilt with no effect. Screenshot added to question.